# MapStruct with MappingTarget in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

I am using MapStruct in my SpringBoot project. The below mapper maps all the fields from the entity to the DTO object of User and Accounts. However ehen trying to do a @MappingTarget after the DTO is mapped the field favourite in UserDTO class is not getting populated with the logic. Requesting to please check the code below and suggest :

**Mapper**

```
@Mapper(uses = AccountMapper.class)
public interface UserMapper {

    UserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "fullName", expression = "java(userMap.getFirstName().concat(\" \").concat(userMap.getLastName()))"),
            @Mapping(target = "createdTime", source = "createdTime", qualifiedByName = "convertDateToString")
    })
    UserDTO userMapToUserDTO(UserMap userMap);

    @Named("convertDateToString")
    default String convertDateToString(Date date){
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        return simpleDateFormat.format(date);
    }

    @Mapping(target="accounts")
    void mapAccounts(@MappingTarget UserMap userMap, UserDTO userDTO);

    @AfterMapping
    default void handleAccounts(@MappingTarget UserMap userMap, UserDTO userDTO) {
        userMap.getAccounts()
                .stream()
                .reduce((ac1, ac2) -> ac1.getBalance()> ac2.getBalance()? ac1 : ac2)
                .stream()
                .map(Account::getAccountNumber)
                .findFirst().ifPresent(userDTO::setFavourite);
    }

}

@Mapper
public interface AccountMapper {

    AccountDTO accountToAccountDTO(Account account);
}
```

**DTO**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserDTO {

    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String fullName;
    private String email;
    private List<Account> accounts;
    private String createdTime;
    private String favourite;

}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AccountDTO {
    private String accountNumber;
    private Integer balance;
}
```

**Output**

UserDTO(id=2, firstName=Tintin, lastName=Haddock, fullName=Tintin Haddock, email=rhdhdhd@gmail.com, accounts=[Account(accountNumber=3422223, balance=3422233), Account(accountNumber=6888989, balance=43242432)], createdTime=2023-10-20 18:22:58, favourite=null)

As you can see the favourite field is null, it is expected to be populated with the accountNumber which has the highest balance. Please suggest

Comment: Resolved..@MappingTarget should be on UserDTO